# Firebase Auth Anonymouse Registration/Login for Android java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to make firebase auth anonymous login for my application. I store this information in firebase realtime. `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` when this person logs out of their account Is it possible to get it back into the same account? I don't want to create a new account, I want to make it login to anonymous account. I am saving uuid during registration. How can I do that?

Lib: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Once a user signs out of an anonymous account there is no way to regain the same UID for that user. If this is a requirement for your app, you will have to implement a custom provider somehow tying the UID of your users to the app instance.

Also see:

- [How constant is the Firebase Anonymous ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854428/how-constant-is-the-firebase-anonymous-id/47856853#47856853)
- [Firebase anonymous will persist when app update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51380387/firebase-anonymous-will-persist-when-app-update/51382639#51382639)
- [Firebase Anonymous Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42040091/firebase-anonymous-authentication/42042028#42042028)
- [firebase anonymous auth tied to device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569040/firebase-anonymous-auth-tied-to-device/68569072#68569072)